# Using Javascript/jQuery to set up Email to SMS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've gotten started on a script, but I'm stuck.

Please review this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/N3kJb/)**

Basically, when the user enters the phone number - ***(You can enter any value right now)***

```
Phone#: <input class="combine" id="input1" value=""></input>
```

I have several hidden inputs that contain values like **"@txt.att.net"**, etc.

```
<input class="combine" id="input3" value="@txt.att.net" style="display: none;"></input>
```

I'm trying to append the input data (phone number), to the various email addresses.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#setVal').on('click', function () {
        var form = $('.combine').not('#outputAddress');
        var vals = form.map(function () {
            var value = $.trim(this.value)
            return value ? value : undefined;
        }).get();
        $('#outputAddress').val(vals.join(';\n '))
    });
});
```

At this point, I've managed to get the input value and the associated domains to display, but I can't get the number to append to the address. The result currently looks like this...

```
inputValue;
 @message.Alltel.com;
 @txt.att.net;
 @myboostmobile.com;
 @sms.mycricket.com;
 @mymetropcs.com;
 @messaging.sprintpcs.com;
 @page.nextel.com;
 @vtext.com;
 @tmomail.net;
 @email.uscc.net;
 @vmobl.com
```

...but needs to look like this instead...

```
inputValue;
 inputValue@message.Alltel.com;
 inputValue@txt.att.net;
 inputValue@myboostmobile.com;
 inputValue@sms.mycricket.com;
 inputValue@mymetropcs.com;
 inputValue@messaging.sprintpcs.com;
 inputValue@page.nextel.com;
 inputValue@vtext.com;
 inputValue@tmomail.net;
 inputValue@email.uscc.net;
 inputValue@vmobl.com
```

...and then ultimately, click the Generate Email button and all the addresses would be placed into the desktop email client (in my case, we need this for Outlook).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the class of the phone number's input and the output's textarea to something else then you can get the values separately:
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dtengeri/nACLK/3/

Change the class of the phone number's to somthing else:

```
Phone#: <input class="input" id="input1" value=""></input>
```

The output could be:

```
<textarea class="output" id="outputAddress" disabled="true" cols="35" rows="13"></textarea>
```

And the Javascipt:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#setVal').on('click', function () {
        // Get the phone number.
        var input = $('.input').val();
        var vals = $('.combine').map(function () {
            var value = $.trim(this.value)
            // Append the phone number before the value.
            return value ? input + value : undefined;
        }).get();
        //Add the phone number to the beginning of the array
        vals.unshift(input);
        $('#outputAddress').val(vals.join(';\n '))
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesomeness! Thanks for the direction. A few things to add to the script, but this is a great push!